# Text with 'text-align:center' got puched to the right after changing margin

Tags: html, css

Basically, I my text was centered on a image with this code:

```
position: absolute;   
z-index: 2;   
display: flex;   
float: center;   
flex-direction: column;   
padding-top: 80vh;     
align-items: center;   
width: 100%;
```

And it was all fint until I decided to  increase  side margins, which resulted in text getting pushed to the right, so oviously they are not centered anymore, even though I did't change the code above, nor  change the left:right proprtion.

Can somebody share their thoughts on what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: If you set position:absolute; then using top, left and  `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` you center the text. Since your code is not at all helpful, i can't tell what you are trying to achieve so this is just a guess. Edit your question with more meaningful code ie with html  and its css.

Comment: Learning to use the dev tools is going to go a long way in debugging these types of things.  You should be able to cover the elements and see what's happening to your margin.

Comment: The code you provided is not sufficient to describe what's going on.